# How to use DATEDIFF for 2 strings in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 columns in a table with a datatype of `varchar`. But I have stored the values as dates like `14/10/2016`. Now I need find the month differents for those 2 columns. I am not able to use the `DATEDIFF` for this because column is declared as `varchar`. Is there is any way to find the difference?

Comment: Yes, use CONVERT() to convert them to datetimes within the DATEDIFF() expression.

Comment: Fix our broken design - if a column stores a date & time, it **must be** `DATETIME` (or `DATETIME2(n)`, in SQL Server 2008 and newer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Conversion method and calculate difference :

```
  SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,CONVERT(DATETIME,'14/10/2016',103),CONVERT(DATETIME,'15/10/2016',103))
```

Answer (score 2):

First, fix your data structure.  In the short term, you can just add correct columns as computed columns:

```
alter table t realdate_col1 as (convert(date, col1, 103));
alter table t realdate_col2 as (convert(date, col2, 103));
```

You should be using the proper types.

In any case, the `convert()` explains what to do:

```
select datediff(day, convert(date, col1, 103), convert(date, col2, 103))
```

Or, go through this process to fix the data:

```
update t
    set col1 = convert(varchar(10), convert(date, col1, 103), 120),
        col2 = convert(varchar(10), convert(date, col2, 103), 120);
```

Then:

```
alter table t alter column col1 date;
alter table t alter column col2 date;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the 'CAST' or 'CONVERT' function so that SQL interprets the data is the data-type you require.

**CAST:**

```
 SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) -- 2017-05-11
```

**CONVERT:**

```
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110) -- 11-05-2017
```

Replace the GETDATE() part with your Date Field. Once you have this working, you can then add this to your DATEDIFF function to convert the varchar field to DATE and then calculate the difference you're after.

There are many variations of the formatting within CONVERT, the '105' represents what format. You can find a list of the formats here:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp